# How to include a blade template in different directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I was already trying to follow the documentation tutorial. But, I always get an error, and I don't know how to solve it

How can I include a blade template in a different directory?

Dashboard.blade.php = in folder views/admin
Landingpage.blade.php = in folder views/admin/subpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@include` directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view.

```php
//resources/views/admin/dashboard.blade.php
@include('admin.dashboard')

//resources/views/admin/subpage/landingpage.blade.php
@include('admin.subpage.landingpage')
```

You can also pass data into the included views.

```php
@include('admin.dashboard', ['user' => $user])
```