# File extension for Laravel Blade as an 'index' page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My 'homepage' for a Laravel install works great, which is: `welcome.blade.php` however, my question is - how do I get other basic 'static' pages to work correctly.

My preferred site top level navigation has for example, 'about us', so what I'd like to do is create a directory called 'about us' and then place a similar page as `blade.index.php` in there but it throws an error.

So, my question is - how do I name the file within a directory within the web application.

Thanks

Comment: Use Laravel Route `routes/web.php` to define new route for your static page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a blade template in different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998128/how-to-include-a-blade-template-in-different-directory)

Comment: Btw, the correct order is `viewName.blade.php`, not `blade.viewName.php`

Answer (score 2):

You've got it flipped. `blade` always goes in the middle.

**index.blade.php**

```php
return view('index');
```

**/about/index.blade.php**

```php
return view('about.index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need put your view file inside static folder of your choice and make sure your filename should contain blade in the middle for ex: "about.blade.php" and after  that you will need to return that file with folder_name/file_name.

```
return view('Folder_name/File_name');
```

Try above code you are good to go.